# How to POST data from link in href tag

Tags: php, html

I have the following code in welcome.php

```
while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo '<tr>  
               <td>'.$i.'</td>  
               <td><a href ="'.$form.'"?MRNum='.$row["patientMRNumber"].'">'.$row["patientEmail"].'<a></td>  
               <td>'.$todayDateOnly.'</td>  
          </tr>';
     $i++;
}
```

Here I am populating a table and can have any number of rows. I need to open a form who's name is saved in $form and want MRNum in that form when this row is clicked.

In the form which is opened, I am trying to get this value, but cant. In the form,

```
$MRnum = (isset($_GET['MRNum'])) ? $_GET['MRNum'] : '';
$_SESSION['MRnum']=$MRnum;
```

Echoing this gives no value.

Comment: `var_dump($_SESSION['MRnum']);`

Comment: This is a much better version than your last posting. You are echoing `$MRnum` on `xyz.php`? Can you add the `echo` code.

Comment: @chris85 It's another post and go; same here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- string '' (length=0) on form

Comment: @chris85 yes I am echoing $MRnum on my form...actually this code works fine when on my welcome.php, I change $form with the actual name, example. 'form.php?MRNum= '

Comment: @Fred-ii- its not a post and go

Comment: seems like you didn't start the session @AIS